# Link Git changeset with TFS workitem

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-workitem

I want to use GIT as source control for the codes and use TFS (Web-access) to manage the progression of the project. So, in TFS I have sprints iterations with workitems.

**Is it possible to link GIT changeset to Workitem?**
Ideally, if we could link them while commiting.
This way, we would known what changed for a given workItem.

I searched on the web and got quite confused about if it can be done and how.
I new with GIT Source control. I'm using both TortoiseGIT and GITExtensions and didn't use any console command so far.

Your answer is appreciated.

Comment: Did you set up TFS to use the Git repository as its version control system? This functionality is available in TFS 2013 and then gives you native support to link Git commits with TFS work items.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tag your commit comment with the #1234 format. Then when you push to your TFS hosted git repository it will be wired up for you.